# How should paths in /etc/paths.d get added to $PATH?

Tags: command-line, bash, path, zsh, macos

None of the paths I have in the `/etc/paths.d` directory are being added to `$PATH` in any of the shells on my High Sierra system.  Presumably there’s supposed to be something in some file that says to look in `/etc/paths.d` when a shell starts; what is that something and where should it be?

Ideally I’d like to know a proper way (i.e. not some weird hack that technically solves the problem but will cause more problems down the line, because that’s almost certainly how I got into this mess) to get `$PATH` to use the contents of `/etc/paths.d` for at least bash and zsh.

Comment: Which shell are you actually using, which shell profiles (`.bashrc` etc.) have you created?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to add `/etc/paths.d` to `PATH`? `PATH` is used by the shell to find executables, and there shouldn't be any in `/etc` or its subfolders.

Comment: @jaume Adding entries (files) to `/etc/paths.d` is an easy way to add path elements systemwide without tampering with `/etc/profile` or `/etc/paths`.

Comment: @nohillside I have `.zshenv`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc`.  I didn’t create any of those, though I have had to mess with them after various install scripts had their way.  I use bash more often than zsh.

Comment: `/etc/profile` gets executed automatically, so maybe one of the `.` profiles overwrites `PATH` for good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/libexec/path_helper` is used to build `PATH` from the default in `/etc/paths` and the entries in `/etc/paths.d` (see `man path_helper` for details). By default this is called in `/etc/profile` which is executed for each `sh`/`bash`/`zsh` style login shell.

On my system `/etc/profile` looks like this

```bsh
# System-wide .profile for sh(1) and friends

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: That first if was what I needed.  Thanks!